# Setting the incident summary on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pagerduty

I have an alerting policy set up in GCP that notifies PagerDuty.

However, the auto generated summary that GCP sends to PagerDuty (which is the same as the summary in GCP's Incident view) is this confusing string of various terms.

Is there a way to explicitly control what is sent in the summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further checking, there is already a filed feature requests for this. You can check these links [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186114287) and [2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163579669). However, for feature requests there is no guarantee of any time frame for updates or that the requested feature will be implemented.